# Is it possible to calculate weight with air pressure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, air, weight

i was wondering if it was possible to calculate a mass of object on top a bag filled in with air
as compared to a bag of air filled up with nothing on top of it
assuming the air pressure going into the bag is constant
Would is be possible to calculate the mass of the object with the different in air pressure going in?

Comment: You would have to know the area with which the weight  has contact. tan you can determine the weight,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'd need to know the contact area in addition to the pressure. The pressure in the bag represents a certain amount of force applied per area. The weight of the object on top of the the bag is supported solely by air pressure - the total force applied is equal to the weight, and can be found by multiplying the pressure by the size of the contact area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but be careful with the calculation.

- As others have said, you need to multiply the pressure by an area.  But use the "effective area", which can be different from the "contact area".  For example, if you are weighing a sphere then you only want the vertical component of the pressure forces.
- If the bag has an initial pressure above atmospheric use the final inflation pressure, not the pressure increase.

Consider an initial pressure $P_0$ greater than atmospheric pressure that inflates the bag into a sphere.  There is a relation between the pressure and the tension in the bag material $T$.

$P_0 = c \cdot T$

where $c$ is a constant that I think is based on the radius of curvature of the bag.

[image]

Now balance a plate on top of the bag and measure the resulting pressure $P_1$.  We can see that that

$P_1 = mg/A$

where $mg$ is the weight of the plate and $A$ is the area of contact.

Combining, we see that the measured pressure difference $P_1 - P_0$ is not equal to $mg/A$, but is instead

$P_1 - P_0 = mg/A - c \cdot T$

**Therefore, using delta pressure times area will underpredict the mass of the plate if there is an initial significant pressure in the bag.**